# CentOS 7 configured for 2FA SSH access via pam_oath - allows any string 6 characters or less for one-time password

Tags: ssh, centos, pam, two-factor-authentication

So I've been reading up on configuring a CentOS 7 machine for 2 factor authentication for SSH, using pam_oath and the FreeOTP phone app, plus local usernames/password for the two factors.  I've read various online articles, and all seem to follow the basic instructions listed in the following articles:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_oath

https://jonarcher.info/2015/07/hardening-ssh-with-otp-for-2-factor-authentication/

https://www.brianlane.com/post/setup-oath-ssh-login-on-fedora/

Before I do this on my main CentOS machine, I spun up a VirtualBox VM for testing, and did a minimum CentOS 7 install.  I followed the instructions, and I get prompted for "One-time password (OATH)" credentials, but I noticed that I can input *any* alphanumeric string that's 6 characters or less for the OATH password, and it will then prompt me for my local username/password.  And as long as I enter the local password correctly, I'm granted shell access.

Here are the steps I followed after the initial minimal CentOS 7 install (CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)):

1. Install packages

```
yum update && yum upgrade

yum install epel-release

yum install pam_oath oathtool gen-oath-safe
```

2. edit /etc/pam.d/sshd, and added the following line as the first non-commented line:

> auth sufficient pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/liboath/users.oath window=10 digits=6

So first few lines of the  /etc/pam.d/sshd look like this before:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
```

And after:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth sufficient pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/liboath/users.oath window=10 digits=6
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
```

3. generate keys for my local account:

> gen-oath-safe jdoe hotp

4. Add key to FreeOTP app on phone via QR code
5. Add the hex code to /etc/liboath/users.oath:

> HOTP jdoe - REDACTED

6. edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and make sure the following settings are in place:

```
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

7. set SELinux permissions on /etc/liboath:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t systemd_passwd_var_run_t '/etc/liboath(/.*)?'
restorecon -rv /etc/liboath/
```

8. Restart SSH:

> systemctl restart sshd

So when I SSH into this host, and enter any string 6 characters or less, I'm let through to login with the local password:

```
login as: jdoe
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
 One-time password (OATH) for `jdoe':
 Password:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Last login: Sun Mar 22 18:03:08 2020 from REDACTED
[jdoe@pkcentos7 ~]
```

If I enter a string 7 characters or more for the OATH password, the following occurs:

```
login as: jdoe
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
 One-time password (OATH) for `jdoe':
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
 One-time password (OATH) for `jdoe':
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
 One-time password (OATH) for `jdoe':
```

I've looked through various other articles returned from Google searches, and I don't clearly see a step or setting I'm missing.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance, and if any additional information is needed, please let me know.

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change pam module control from `sufficient` to `[success=done new_authtok_reqd=done default=die]`

My pam line looks like:

```
auth [success=done new_authtok_reqd=done default=die] pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/users.oath
```

*sshd_config*:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam 
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply!  From looking at your sshd_config file, I assume that you're using a public key as part of the 2FA on your system.  So I tweaked what you have above to work on my test system:

1) /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
auth [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok default=die]  pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/liboath/users.oath window=10 digits=6
```

2) /etc/sshd/sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive:pam
```

Here's what the output from the SSH login process after this change, where I:

1) purposely entered one-time password wrong

2) entered correct one-time, but wrong account password

3) correct one-time password, then correct account password

```
login as: jdoe
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| One-time password (OATH) for `jdoe':
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| One-time password (OATH) for `jdoe':
| Password:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| One-time password (OATH) for `jdoe':
| Password:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Last failed login: Thu Apr 16 10:55:39 EDT 2020 from REDACTED on ssh:notty
There were 2 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
Last login: Thu Apr 16 10:54:59 2020 from REDACTED
[jdoe@pkcentos7 ~]$
```